# How can I see what files changed for each commit in bazaar?

Tags: command-line, bazaar

In git, I can use `git log --stat` to see which files changed in a commit. How can I do that in bzr?

```
$ git log --stat

commit dbdc98ccc1ce12a31a0bf29173b4990ccbff98
Author: Me <Me@Me.com>
Date:   Thu Jan 29 19:03:10 2011 -0800

    Add snipMate v0.83

 vim/after/plugin/snipMate.vim     |   35 ++
 vim/autoload/snipMate.vim         |  433 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 vim/doc/snipMate.txt              |  286 +++++++++++++++++
```

`bzr viz` doesn't show changed files either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bzr log --verbose` will list the files under a `modified:` header.

Also, `bzr help` and `bzr help <command>` are helpful.